# How to make RDoc use gemspec configuration

Tags: ruby, rdoc

In my gemspec file, I've added configuration for RDoc that doesn't seem to be seen by RDoc.

```
gem.rdoc_options = ['-m', 'README.md']
```

Given that I've specified the README.md file as the main file, I would expect that running `rdoc` would respect that. It doesn't. Running `rdoc -m README.md` does work, but then why even have it in the gemspec?

Answer (score 0):

http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Gem/Specification/rdoc_options%3D suggests that this should not be used and that you should push options onto the array instead. Maybe try that?

```
gem.rdoc_options<<'-m'<<'README.md'
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either. Do I need to somehow point RDoc at my gemspec for it to see the settings?

Comment: No, quite sure you don't. You might find http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/ useful (though it suggests the same thing).